# Connecting Power BI to BigQuery issue - SSL verification failed

Tags: ssl, google-bigquery, powerbi

I am trying to connect Power BI to BigQuery, but am getting the error below preventing this. I had previously been able to connect without issue, but in the last month have been unable to due to this error.

I have updated Power BI to the latest version, tried the instructions mentioned in the solution here (https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Bigquery-connection-error/td-p/1602196), but nothing has worked.

How can I get around this SSL verification issue?

Error Message:
Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverSupport] (1120) SSL verification failed because the server host name specified for the connection does not match the "CN" entry in the "Subject" field or any of the "DNS Name" entries of the "Subject Alternative Name" field in the server certificate.
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverSupport] (1120) SSL verification failed because the server host name specified for the connection does not match the "CN" entry in the "Subject" field or any of the "DNS Name" entries of the "Subject Alternative Name" field in the server certificate."

Comment: It might be a firewall issue, see [here](https://simba.wpengine.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/bq/features/endpoints.htm) the list of endpoints that should be whitelisted also found on the page 56 of Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery.pdf in the driver folder.
You might also check the [driver-manager logs](https://simba.wpengine.com/blog/odbc-troubleshooting-tracing/)

Comment: If you are using Excel, it might also be a conflict from the MS Office versions. For example, if you have MS Office 32 bit version and you installed Simba ODBC 64 bit driver it will cause issues.

Comment: Also check any security application that might be blocking the connection.